# Help identify this iPad drawing app

Tags: ipad, drawing

I am trying to find a drawing app for iPad, and I came across this one being used to teach courses. Can anyone help identify the app?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Notability

This appears to be [Notability](http://gingerlabs.com) by Ginger Labs:

> Combine handwriting, photos and typing in a single note to bring your projects to life. Use a wide range of note-taking and sketching tools to capture every detail. You can even add and annotate PDFs in Notability. It’s the perfect place to create and organize work, school, and life's information!

[image: Notability web site image]